# Передать два php в HttpPost

Tags: android

Хочу передать в android studio два php файла в одном HttpPost, но как-то туплю, помогите пожалуйста.

```
public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User>  {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
     protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSent = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSent.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSent.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php" + "JsonUser.php");

        User returnedUser = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSent));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if(jObject.length() == 0){
                returnedUser = null;
            }   else{
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                returnedUser = new User(name, age, user.username, user.password);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;

    }
}
```

Comment: Пытаетесь передать или пытаетесь запросить?

Answer (score 2):

```java
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php" + "JsonUser.php");
```

Здесь вы создаете объект HTTP-POST-запроса, и в качестве URI задаёте строку склеенную из адреса сервера, строки "FetchUserData.php" и строки "JsonUser.php". В результате склейки строк у вас получается что-то вроде:

> http://example.com/FetchUserData.phpJsonUser.php

В ответ, вы видимо хотите данные, которые вернутся по запросам к этим двум php-скриптам.

Однако HTTP-серверы не умеют как-то интеллектуально разделять подобные строки, и тем более, они не умеют одновременно возвращать несколько результатов для одного запроса.

Во первых, вам необходимо разделить эти запросы:

```java
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "JsonUser.php");
```

Во вторых, собственно разделить всю нижеследующую за ними логику.